# Is it possible to run both Istio and gRPC in a GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

Istio and gRPC seem complementary and I'd like to use both in the clusters.

The thing is that they both add an extra container which receives/proxy communication between pods / microservices.

Is it advised or not to use both in parallel in all pods?

Are there particular adaptations to do if one uses both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Istio and gRPC do work well together, when declaring your services ports' to istio just make sure to name them `grpc-something` so the proxy knows it is h2/grpc traffic and route it properly

You mention that gRPC adds an extra container - why not having your service speak gRPC natively ?

We do have future plans with protocol transcoding and rich integrated gRPC/istio libraries that would skip layers but that's not there yet.

Comment: the extra container is due to google endpoints in gke. It is their ExtensibleServiceProxy which enables REST/GRPC transcoding. https://github.com/cloudendpoints/esp. Do you still think it will work with Istio? It means having 2 proxy in the same pod. A bit heavy maybe.

Comment: I'm sure it will eventually get optimized/combined but I have no idea when, sorry.

Comment: Actually you are right, esp are present only on the edge, it interacts with endpoints. They are not needed 'inside' the cluster. So it should work. I will indicate here when I have validated the solution on my end.

Comment: With the recommended way to put Istio on GKE, by default all egress requests are blocked. That stops the ESP from working since it needs to retrieve data from outside the Istio mesh, so you need to open up some egress channels for that. I'm still trying to work out exactly what URLs the ESP needs to access.